# Синхронизация подписки на Observable

Tags: java, mongodb, rxjava, синхронизация

O работе с асинхронщиной знаю только теорию, на практике не работал
работаю с mongodb-async-driver + mongodb-driver-rx
у меня есть запрос на добавление транзакций, который может выполняться из множества потоков. Для выполнения этого запроса он должен получить данные из бд, обновить их. У меня получается так, что два потока в одно время получают одинаковые данные из бд и выполняют операции по их обновлению, хотя должны делать это по очереди.

вот метод, который вызывается асинхронно

```
@Override
public void addTransaction(Transaction tr) {
    final Bson inputFilter = Filters.eq("_id", tr.getInputId());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + " начал искать инпут");

    Observer<Input> observer = new Observer<>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
            subscription.request(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Input input) {
           выполняем кучу работы по обновлению данных в бд
            только по её заверешению нужно дать доступ другому потоку на добавление транзакций
           });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при получении Input'ов " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("Добавление завершено");
        }
    };

  //подписка не должна происходить, пока происходит работа с бд
    Observables.observe(collectionInput.find(inputFilter)
            .map(QiwiInput::fromDocument)).subscribe(observer);
}
```

Пытался синхронизировать следующим образом

```
   private boolean isUpdate = false;
   
   @Override
    public void addTransaction(Transaction tr) {
        final Bson inputFilter = Filters.eq("_id", tr.getInputId());
        System.out.println("Начинаем искать инпуты");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
       
        synchronized(MongDB.this){
        if(isUpdate)
            wait();
        }
        Observables.observe(collectionInput.find(inputFilter)
                .map(QiwiInput::fromDocument)).subscribe(new Observer<>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                isUpdate = true;
                subscription.request(1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Input input) {
                System.out.println(input.getCommissionBalance().getNumber());
                System.out.println("ща буим добавлять");
                //как закончили операцию
                isUpdate = false;
                MongoDB.this.notifyAll();
               
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка при получении Input'ов " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                System.out.println("Добавление завершено");
            }
        });
    }
```

но этот код выдает `IllegalMonitorStateException` на строке, где я вызываю `notify`. Подскажите, как быть

Answer (score -1):

Вы используете синхронизацию на мониторе `MongDB.this`, в момент когда вы хотите послать сообщение другим потокам, ваш метод вызывающий `notify()` уже находится за пределами синхронизации, то есть монитор уже отсутствует.

Вы можете пользоваться `notify()` когда у вас есть монитор. В противном случае попытка вызвать `notify()` на несуществующий монитор будет вызывать `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: те, мне нужно MongoDB.this.notifyAll(); в syncronized(MongDB.this) обрамить?

Comment: да, так и нужно

Comment: сделал, теперь нет ошибки, просто поток не просыпается

Comment: а зачем вы его усыпляете?

Comment: Ну, чтоб он не начинал операцию, пока поток, который пришел раньше, не закончит

Comment: У меня там даже в методе строка, которая усыпляет, если уже началась операция обновления

Comment: Вы как-то там контролируйте каким монитором пользуетесь

Comment: Я вешаю на MongDb монитор и по нему уже работаю. Перед вызовом notifyAll() делаю syncronized(Mongdb.this)

Comment: Это ни очем не говорит, точнее это я уже смотрел.

Comment: А как ещё можно контролировать тогда?

Comment: Для того, чтобы начать изучать методы синхронизации, надо иметь представление об объектном мониторе. На ваш вопрос я ответил, но  то что вы пишете в коментариях к моему ответу не имеет ни малейшего отношения.

Comment: В смысле? Если это не помогло, мб не нужно оставлять бесполезные комментарии?

Comment: @ВладиславСултаняров Коментарии под вопросом пишутся для того чтобы помочь улучшить вопрос, а под ответом чтобы помочь улучшить ответ. Все остальные комментарии бесполезны.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.